# How to align PYPDF content to bottom left of the cell

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

Pretty standard request, but it doesn't appear there's a lot available.

I am using the package:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
```

And wish to align my content to the bottom left of a cell. Well obviously you'd use 'L', however the cell to the left of it is larger and therefore if I was to limit the cells height, it would be above, rather then bottom of the content.

For example, my code:

```
pdf.cell(WIDTH/25, HEIGHT/19, '+7', 1, 0, 'L')

pdf.set_font(custom_font_name, '', 30)
pdf.cell(WIDTH/15, HEIGHT/19, 'above',1,1, 'L')
```

I wish to align this cell to the bottom left, so that above is written in the same manner as it would appear if written standard.

Content to be aligned to the bottom left:

```
pdf.cell(WIDTH/15, HEIGHT/19, 'above',1,1, 'L')
```

This is within a larger function which calculates page 1.
Any ideas?

I've tried various ways, thru documentation and creating functions to identify co-ordinates but no bueno.